# Early 90s sci fi movie with antichrist in stasis on derelict vessel

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is annoying the hell out of me so I'm hoping someone can put me out of my misery.

The film's plot is about the crew of a spacecraft who come upon a derelict vessel containing a guy in stasis. After taking him aboard their own ship it turns out that he is the antichrist.

The rest of the film is him killing off the crew, and at the end the last remaining crew member on board remote fires a missile from a military satellite destroying the ship, himself and the antichrist.

I think the last thing the crew member says to the antichrist is "I'll see you in hell"

Hope someone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know when the film was made and whether it was British, American or maybe somewhere else.

Comment: Film was American. Exactly when it was made I can't say. Very late 80s to early 90s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty sure this is [Dark Side of the Moon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099364/) from 1990.

It matches on several points, although I don't remember them finding anyone in stasis. The plot includes finding a derelict Space Shuttle, the devil possessing different crew members and the missile/"see you in hell" scene you describe at the end.

Comment: Just looked up the trailer for this on youtube, and it is the movie I've been searching for. Not sure why I thought there was a guy in stasis, just shows how the memory can play tricks.

Comment: The whole movie is on YouTube as a matter of fact.

Comment: ...and  i go and hit enter before thanking you.

Comment: ..and I've gone and done it again! Thanks again for for your help with this, much appreciated.

Comment: No problem. If you accept the answer it'll help people in the future, though (and give me Meaningless Internet Points)

Comment: This plot line is just like "Cruise Into Terror", a 1978 B-Movie where people on a ship find a sarcophagus in the Bermuda Triangle, which holds the Antichrist in stasis. It causes the people to go crazy and kill eachother or protect the sarcophagus. This was a very creepy movie for me when I was a kid, especially since the little baby sized evil sarcophagus would have its chest move in and out as if it was breathing! Of course you can find it on IMDB, www.braineater.com/cruise.html  has an interesting set of facts as well.